# Popover not working HTML 5

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, popover

```
<h4>Text <i class="icon-question-sign clickable" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="The values” data-original-title="Text "></i></h4>

<h4>Schedules <i class="icon-question-sign clickable" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="The values provided" data-original-title="Schedules"></i></h4>
```

I am using following code to make the popover appear in my code. But no popover appears. What is going wrong? what am I missing.

I am using Html 5, MVC framework C#. This code is in View

Comment: I do not think this is your problem, but you seem to use two single quotes instead of a double quote in your first line beside "The values".

Comment: You have to read the docs, popovers and tooltips are initiated by jQuery that you write yourself, it's not automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### [Opt-in functionality](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)
>
> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning **you must initialize them yourself**.

This means doing, for example:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

(And you must also call `$(...).popover()` manually for elements with popovers that get added after the initial page load.)